# Find parent environment within call stack by function name

Tags: r, callstack

I'm working in a call stack of variable depth that looks like

```
TopLevelFunction
 -> <SomeOtherFunction(s), 1 or more>
   -> AssignmentFunction
```

Now, my goal is to assign a variable created in `AssignmentFunction`, to the environment of `TopLevelFunction`. I know I can extract the stack with `sys.calls`, so my current approach is

```
# get the call stack and search for TopLevelFunction
depth <- which(stringr::str_detect(as.character(sys.calls()), "TopLevelFunction"))
# assign in TopLevelFunction's environment
assign(varName, varValue, envir = sys.frame(depth))
```

I'm more or less fine with that, though I am not sure if that's a good idea to convert call objects to character vectors. Is that approach error-prone? More generally, how would you search for a specific parent environment, knowing only the name of the function?

Answer (score 1):

A fn like this

```
get_toplevel_env <- function(env) {

    if (identical(parent.env(env), globalenv())) {
        env
    } else {
        get_toplevel_env(parent.env(env))
    }
}
```

And use it within any level of your nested-functions like this?

```
get_toplevel_env(as.environment(-1))
```

Comment: I appreciate your input, but do you have any arguments concerning why your solution is preferable to mine?

Comment: well, for one thing, in your solution, you hard-coded the name of the top level function. It works, but it may not be so good for the maintainability of your code (if your top level fn changes, you have to change your code). Also, it is not immediately reusable/transferable to other context (it only works for that specific fn). The function I suggest is generic and it will find the top level environment in any call stack, regardless of the name of the function. Maybe you do not care about that, but to me is always important to care about maintainability and reusability of the code I write

Comment: Fair point, thanks. Though I could always turn function name into a parameter (as a matter of fact, I already did that) :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly what you want to do, but, woulnd't it work to use `parent.env(as.environment(-1))`?

In this example it seems to work.

```
fn1 <- function() {

    fn1.1 <- function(){
        assign("parentvar", "PARENT", 
               envir = parent.env(as.environment(-1)))

    }

    fn1.1()
    print(parentvar)
}

fn1()
```

Maybe other possibility is to use `<<-`, which assigns in the global environment, I think. But maybe that's not what you want.

Comment: Good idea, but it won't work if I nest more functions between `AssignmentFunction` and `TopLevelFunction`. In my situation, the call stack may be, say, 3 or 5 functions deep, so I am forced to extract the whole stack. As for global assignment, it is usually frowned upon since affects the global state, so I'd do my best to avoid it.

Comment: Ahh, I see, so what if you recursively get the parent environment until you reach just before the global environment?., ..., the code here looks horrible, so I'll post another answer ...